# Parse - Updating PFObject iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to edit a value of a saved PFObject of the PFUser. I want the user to be able to edit the value in a text field then press "save". I do not know how to get the object I'd or retrieve and edit that object.

Here is how I save the object:

```
-(IBAction)SaveObj
{
PFObject *obj =[PFObject objectWithClassName:@"client"];
[obj [[Name] text] objectForKey:@"Name"];
[obj save];
}
```

Comment: Have you completed the Parse.com tutorials?  https://parse.com/tutorials  If not then I recommend that you take a look

Comment: Yes! I just don't know how to edit that object. @Paulw11

Comment: You need to show a lot more code.  If you already have your client object in a property or variable then you can use `[obj setObject:yourNameTextField.text forKey:@"Name"];`  If not then you will need to use a PFQuery to obtain the object.  Your current code creates a new client object.  Perhaps re-visit the Parse tutorials and example code, as what you are asking is fairly straight-forward.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you did while setting up the parse . Just make sure following things :

1. Check whether you have created Apple Push Notification certificate correctly.
2. Also make sure you have enable Push notification to your provisioning profile.
3. And last check you have entered right application ID and client key from the parse.com

You can follow the tutorial : https://www.parse.com/tutorials

Comment: Don't think you understood, I know how to save the object as stated but I don't know how to edit the object after I saved it from the app

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about push notifications